# ¿Cómo puedo pegar el contenido de un JTextArea a un archivo .txt creado por el mismo codigo en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, archivo, jframe, filewriter

estoy tratando de enviar el texto que tengo en un JTextArea a el archivo que tambien crea mi codigo. Ya he tratado con el getText() usando FileWriter y utilizando variables para guardar el contenido del JTextArea y pegarlo en el archivo tambien con FileWriter y ninguna de las dos maneras me sirve, el archivo sigue vacio. 
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
contenidoMarca = marca.getText();
contenidoCantidad = cantidad.getText();

public static void escribirArchivo() {
           try {
                FileWriter escritorArchivoPedido = new FileWriter(nombreArchivo);
                escritorArchivoPedido.write(contenidoMarca);
                escritorArchivoPedido.write(contenidoCantidad);
                escritorArchivoPedido.close();
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que el archivo queda vacío? Acabé de probar tu código y no queda vacío. ¿Verificaste si la ruta del archivo es correcta?

Comment: @MrDave1999 acabo de checar que imprime dentro del archivo que se crea en la carpeta del proyecto, pero no se imprime nada en el archivo que se crea en el path especificado (nombreArchivo)